# Get Facebook Post Data (likes, comments, shares)

Tags: facebook, api, post

i searched a lot and still didn't find a good (and simple) way to get likes, shares and comments for my posts in Facebook. Maybe through the Graph API? But I'm not sure how to build the query, anyone can help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likes: `/v2.3/<object_id>/likes` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/likes

Comments: `/v2.3/<object_id>/comments` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/comments

Shares: `/v2.3/<object_id>/sharedposts` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/sharedposts

This is information you could get from Google.

This is a good resource about [getting started with the Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview).